# complete shatter

Tags: modeling

As part of the project I spoke about previously the floor is supposed to shatter into pieces and sink into the lava, however when I employ cell fracture There are massive mesh Gaps like so
[image]

That was a simple 4 sided plane with some thickness.
How can I get a complete fractured item?
To be clear this was the original mesh
[image]

It was taken from the top of orthographic mode but it is just a solidified plane

Comment: Discussion about tags and reputation is best suited for [meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/). I guess it would help showcasing your mesh before the fracture. Is you geometry manifold?

Comment: When referring to other questions please put a link as part of the text of the question

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my own question. The mesh I was using was a single face, by applying subdivide 3 or 4 times on edit mode not only did I get a complete set of shattered geometry, but I got more, smaller, better looking fragments as well.